# Differences between C++ compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation

While working on my assignment for data structures today, I came across a few errors I had to address that were very new to me. For example, the following:

```
struct Node
{
  // data and stuff

 Node(const T& d = T{}, Node * const p = nullptr, 
     Node * const n = nullptr, unsigned int f = 0)
     : data(d), prev(p), next(n), freq(f) {}

  // other stuff
};
```

This ran perfectly fine in visual studio, but not however in g++. I had to change nullptr to 0, even though visual studio wanted me to use nullptr!

Another incident using the school's compiler gave me the following message:

```
warning:  extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x
```

So naturally I went ahead and added this to my makefile.

This got me wondering, how often will I see errors result from simple differences in compilers, given that I will be writing more complex programs in the future? Is visual studio not backwards compatible with older compilers? Can I change settings? Just looking for general knowledge of things I should be aware of when it comes to using various compilers.

Comment: You should tell g++ that you are building c++11 code, by adding the ``-std=c++11`` switch. g++ will by default compile (I think) in C++03 mode.

Comment: `nullptr` is a C++11 thing, and gcc doesn't compile in C++11 by default, whereas newer versions of VS do.

Comment: "how often will I see errors result from simple differences in compilers" - if you don't know about anything about the difference between versions of the C++ standards and *configuring* your compiler, then often. Else, not so often. "Is visual studio not backwards compatible with older compilers?" - that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Alternatively, he can avoid C++11 constructs.  VS will accept `NULL` instead of `nullptr`, and `T()` instead of `T{}`.  Since he's talking about "school", I suspect that his prof will want to compile the results himself, and will _not_ use the `-std=c++11` option when he does so.  (Regretfully, I don't know of a way to get VS to warn about new features.  But he could always install g++ on his PC, and use that.)

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with how compilers work exactly. That probably wasn't the best terminology. What I was asking was, can a compiler like visual studio recognize 0 as a nullptr even if it expects the latter?
James - yes, I was concerned about my professor recieving my assignment and compiling with a different version, although I am giving him my makefile.

Comment: As additional note, the generated warning (-std=c++0x) makes reference to the current standard c++11, but some years before the publishing of C++11 (the last one was C++03), it was known as C++0x, because it was expected for 2008 or 2009. Currently, gcc accept both -std=c++0x and -std=c++11 as synonyms options to enable the new features of the language.

Comment: And you can thing about pointers as integers. Anything transformable to `int`, can be assigned to pointers. `nullptr` is only a new keyword which represents a null pointer (of type nullptr_t), and can be casted to bool (as false), to int (as 0), or to any other pointer type (int*, Node*, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g++` will by default compile in C++03 mode, which was the C++ standard before C++11. To tell `g++` that your code is in fact C++11 code, you have to use the `-std=c++11` compiler switch. For example:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cc
```

Comment: Ahh that is very useful to know! I guess this is something simple I should have been aware of.

Comment: Although what @JamesKanze says is true: If whoever is checking the assignments is not using C++11, that won’t help you. You might want to ask them, and in case of doubt always compile with g++ in C++03 mode. And with ``-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror``.

Comment: I emailed a few minutes ago to be safe. I think I will stick with 03 for now. And yes, I am using -pedantic -Wall. I haven't encountered -Wextra -Werror yet! I will read up on them now. Thanks so much.